# Syntax error : end of file unexpected (expecting "fi")

Tags: bash, makefile

I am writing a makefile in bash and I have a target in which I try to find if a file exists and even though I think the syntax is correct, i still gives me an error.

Here is the script that I am trying to run

```
read: 
        if [ -e testFile] ; then \ 
        cat testFile\ 
        fi
```

I am using tabs so that is not a problem.

The error is (when I type in: "make read")

```
if [ -e testFile] ; then \
        cat testFile \
        fi
/bin/sh: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "fi")
make: *** [read] Error 2
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try adding a semicolon after `cat testFile`.  For example:

```
read: 
    if [ -e testFile ] ; then  cat testFile ; fi
```

alternatively:

```
read:
    test -r testFile && cat testFile
```

Comment: the alternate solution works but I have to use the if..then syntax. adding a semicolon does not seem to solve the issue.

Comment: Weird. I tried it the first time with semicolon and it didnt work. th second time I ran it it worked.Thanks

Comment: Just a note to self: I originally wrote plain multiline `bash` statements in the makefile, and had the same failure - and as this answer notes, the trick is to have the makefile recognize the shell command as a single line; hence I'd need _both_ semicolon `;` (to separate shell commands) _and_ backslash `\\` (to escape the subsequent newline) to get it to work... Cheers!

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/18554356/2336934

Answer (score 9):

I ran into the same issue.  This should do it:

```
file:
    @if [ -e scripts/python.exe ] ; then \
    echo TRUE ; \
    fi
```

Answer (score 5):

Since GNU Make 3.82, you can add `.ONESHELL:` to the top of the file to tell make to run all the lines within a target in a single shell.

```
.ONESHELL:
SHELL := /bin/bash

foobar:
    if true
    then
        echo hello there
    fi
```

See the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/One-Shell.html).

Prepend lines with `@` or add the `.SILENT:` option beneath `.ONESHELL:` to suppress echoing lines.

Answer (score 2):

I also met this problem.

And the reason is that I added some comments after the "\".