# Syntax error: "then" unexpected (expecting "fi")

Tags: shell, if-statement

I am writing a shell script for a file, it gives me this error:

I am quite certain that the syntax is correct. I dont know what the error is

```
if[ "$check" = "rename" ]; then
      echo "now "
else
      echo "blub"
fi
```

I know its a duplicate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764908/syntax-error-end-of-file-unexpected-expecting-fi). I have tried this(Alternative section of the first solution) as well. :(. It still does not work for me

Comment: "I am quite certain that the syntax is correct." I think you'll find this is a dangerous statement to make. 8-)}

Answer (score 9):

You are missing a space after the keyword if.

```
if [ $check == "rename" ]; then
```

should work.

Comment: That works now! Thanks!. Sorry, for deleting the comment.

Just in case you have idea why this occurs: `Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution
`

Comment: That must be from some other snippet of code than what is mentioned in your question.

Comment: @user1524529 - don't forget to click the checkmark for the correct answer.

Comment: :( That's the error that I still incur : Syntax error: `EOF in backquote substitution`

Comment: You must have a line with back-quote `\`` that's missing an ending back-quote `\``.

Answer (score 1):

I got this kind of error when I accidentally ran a script with `#!/bin/sh` instead of `#!/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @Lenar Hoyt led me to the solution of similar problem. In my case I had accidentally inserted space in the very beginning of the script, so instead of

```
#!/bin/bash
```

I had

```
 #!/bin/bash
```

...so probably "wrong" shell was used. As soon as I removed the space, it worked.