# If not exists, create a folder - Error in makefile

Tags: linux, shell, makefile

I searched over the internet for a command to create a folder if it doesn't exist. I found it and put in my makefile

```
.DEFAULT_GOAL := all
folder := "myfolder"

createfolder:
    [ ! -d ${folder} ] && mkdir -p ${folder}

nextstep:
    echo "Got here!"

all: createfolder nextstep
```

When the folder doesn't exist it's created correctly. But I get an error if the folder already exists.

```bash
$ ls
makefile
$ make
[ ! -d "myfolder" ] && mkdir -p "myfolder"
echo "Got here!"
Got here!
$ ls
makefile  myfolder
$ make
[ ! -d "myfolder" ] && mkdir -p "myfolder"
make: *** [makefile:5: createfolder] Error 1
```

I don't get why the command would give an error if the condition `[ ! -d "myfolder" ]` is before the `mkdir` and it shouldn't even execute the second command.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Why not use if then fi syntax ?

Comment: `nextstep` should be dependent on `createfolder`.   If the above is run with `-j`, you could get a race condition with `nextstep` running before `createfolder` completes.    Plus, `createfolder` should be declared as `.PHONY`, or better yet, renamed to the name of the folder (and then put as an _order-only_ dependency to whatever requires it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is what make is for.

```
${folder}: 
        mkdir -p ${folder}
```

Comment: Also note, that `${folder}` in this case should be an [order-only](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html) dependency (a folder's modification date is updated anytime anything in the folder is changed, which could make this target seem out of date when it's not).

Comment: @HardcoreHenry  Out of date with respect to what? There are no dependencies in the rule.

Comment: if you had, for example, `${folder}/foo.o ${folder}/bar.o: ${folder}`, and then you did a build, the creation of `bar.o` would update the timestamp of `${folder}`.   If you then did a subsequent build without modifying anything, `${folder}` would (likely) be newer than `${folder}/foo.o` and therefore it would rebuild `foo.o` and all its dependencies, even though nothing changed.    Therefore the proper way to do this would be `${folder}/foo.o : | ${folder}`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to create folders is to use [order-only prerequisites](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html):

```
%/.:
    mkdir -p "$@"
```

With that, you can reliably create directories for any rule:

```
nextstep: | $(folder)/.
    ...
```

If you enable [secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html), you can use the same trick for arbitrary compilation rules:

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.c | $$(@D)/.
    ...
```

so just tack `| $$(@D)/.` at the end of the rule and you're all set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if` `then` `fi` syntax

```
.DEFAULT_GOAL := all
folder := "myfolder"

createfolder:
        if [ ! -d ${folder} ]; then mkdir -p ${folder}; fi

nextstep:
        echo "Got here!"

all: createfolder nextstep
```

Comment: Thank you! When I tried dividing it in lines, I was receiving an syntax error like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18155852/syntax-error-end-of-file-unexpected-expecting-then). The one line command solved my problem.

Comment: Just run `mkdir -p`.  That's what the `-p` is for.  You don't have to check if the directory exists first: if you use `-p` then `mkdir` will create the directory if it doesn't exist, or silently succeed if it does exist.

Comment: And so, stark's answer should be accepted instead.