# Call AWS CodeBuild project from CodePipeline with different parameters

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-codebuild

Let's imagine that we have one CodePipeline with 2 stages in the following fashion:

```
new codepipeline.Pipeline(this, name + "Pipeline", {
    pipelineName: this.projectName + "-" + name,
    crossAccountKeys: false,
    stages: [{
        stageName: 'Source',
        actions: [codeCommitSourceAction]
    },{
        stageName: 'Build',
        actions: [buildAction]
    }]
});
```

Here the *Source* stage is where we pull the changes from the repository and the *Build* one is a CodeBuild project which has the following actions in the `buildspec` file:

1. Install the dependencies (`npm i`).
2. Run the tests (`npm run test`).
3. Pack the project (`npm run pack`).
4. Update/deploy lambda function (`aws lambda update-function-code`).

In general it does what it supposed to do, however, if the build fails, the only way to find out, which part has failed, is to look to the logs. I would like that it is seen straight from CodePipeline. In this case CodePipeline must have more stages which correlate with each action from CodeBuild. Based on my experience I can do it if for every stage I provide different CodeBuild project.

*Question: can I provide same CodeBuild project to the different CodePipeline stages so, that it will execute only part of buildspec file (for example, only running the tests)?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your `buildspec.yml` perform different actions based on environment variables. You can then pass different environment variables to [CodeBuildAction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-codepipeline-actions.CodeBuildAction.html) with [environmentVariables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-codepipeline-actions.CodeBuildActionProps.html#environmentvariables).

```js
new codepipeline_actions.CodeBuildAction({
  actionName: 'Build',
  project: buildProject,
  input: sourceInput,
  runOrder: 1,
  environmentVariables: {
    STEP: { value: 'test' }
  }
}),
```

And then check `STEP` environment variable in `buildspec.yml`.

Comment: yes, that worked, thanks! In case somebody searched how to use environment variable in JSON format, it is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62881332/conditional-statement-in-codebuild-commands-json/70493852#70493852

Answer (score 0):

> Question: can I provide same CodeBuild project to the different CodePipeline stages so, that it will execute only part of buildspec file (for example, only running the tests)?

No, I don't think that is possible.

What you can do however, is to have different `buildspecs.yml` file called at different stages of your pipeline.

For example, you could have a `Codepipeline` stage called `Init` which will call the `builspec_init.yml` of your project. If that succeed, you could have a following state `Apply` calling the `buildspec_apply.yml` file of your project.